# What does this notation "/^\s*$/.test(val)" mean

Tags: javascript

What does this "/^\s*$/" mean as I tried to learn it from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions but can't get it meaning?

```js
fn: function (val) {
  return typeof val === 'string' ? 
  !/^\s*$/.test(val) : val !== undefined && val !== null;
}
```

Comment: From the URL you wrote: ^  : Matches beginning of input. 
\s : Matches a single character other than white space. 
* : Matches the preceding expression 0 or more times.
$ : Matches end of input. 

1+2+3+4 : Matches a string that begin and end with 0 or many white spaces.

Comment: @KavishMehta, did you accept and then unaccept my answer? Is there anything else unclear?

Comment: @Maximus sorry I double click it

Comment: @KavishMehta, no problem, just wondered if it was a glitch, good luck)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
/^\s*$/
```

is a [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

The code snippet

```
/^\s*$/.test(val)
```

uses RegExp [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method to test whether a string `val` is empty or only contains spaces. From the docs:

> The test() method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

If you take a look at this regex in  [this tutorial](https://regex101.com/r/MihtGE/1), it will show you the following explanation:

```
^ asserts position at start of the string
    \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
      * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

Basically, it means that:

```
/^...$/
```

matches a string from the beginning to the end, and

```
\s*
```

matches zero or more occurrences of white space characters

Answer (score 3):

Here **^** means the beginning of expression.

**\s*** means 0 or more occurrences of space characters(' ', tab etc)

**$** means end of the string.

so `/^\s*$/` is the regex for empty string or string with only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\s*$/
```

first /{regex is here}/ is how u write regex here

^{somethingelse}$ is meaning started and ended in the middle regex

\s is any string character

'*' means zero or more

so it means all the element is character, not a number or symbol or spaces